# How to perform a join on two tables in an SSIS package, where the table names are dynamic

Tags: sql-server, join, ssis

Just for reference, this question is more or less a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930161/trying-to-loop-through-and-delete-from-a-list-of-tables-using-ssis/47932882?noredirect=1#comment82889473_47932882) which I asked a few weeks ago.  In that case I suspect the problem was essentially that I had picked up someone else's incomplete code and was trying to update it without completely understanding what they'd been trying to do.  The issue I'm running into now I expect has more to do with the fact that I'm not familiar with SSIS and as such do not know which tools (i.e. data flows and joins) I need to use to do what I want.

I'm working on a purging process which queries a table that contains the names of tables which need to be purged, and loops through the table names provided to actually perform the purge.  Because SSIS doesn't allow tables to be assigned to variables, I accomplished this by creating a variable with the following:

```
"DELETE FROM " + @[User::TableName] + " WHERE CreateDate < DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE())"
```

and creating an Execute SQL task to run with that variable as the SQL query.  The TableName value is being passed from the foreach loop I am using to query the table I mentioned before.

The problem I'm running into now is that I need to modify the purge process to be able to join the table being purged with the associated table in our archive database, to make sure I am only purging records which have already been archived.  Because these tables will have the same name but exist in different databases, I had hoped I would be able to just use the TableName value twice for the join.  However, none of the ways I've tried to implement this seem to work. Specifically I seem to run into issues when trying to alias the two tables being joined.  I've seen some people with similar issues who solved them by creating two OLE DB source objects corresponding to the two tables, and using the SSIS merge join to join them.  However, I haven't been able to get that to work, because SSIS doesn't seem to be able to create a source object from a dynamic table name.  Or I don't know how to make it do that at least.

Thanks for any help you can provide and let me know if I can provide any other information.  It's been a few weeks since I touched this project so I'm kind of refreshing myself on how I had it working so I apologize if anything was unclear.

Comment: Did you try qualifying the table variables with the database names? e.g. variable1 = dbname.schema.tablename, variable2 = db2name.schema2.tablename. I'm able to join tables with the same name in different databases using an Execute SQL Task so long as the names are qualified. That requires that they're on the same server... If not, you'd need to use a linked server.

Comment: I remember trying this a few weeks ago and running into issues, but it's possible I only tried qualifying one of the two tables in question.  I will try with both and let you know what the results are.

Comment: Are the two databases on the same server?

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, they are

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying the SQL in your variable to use 3-part naming and do the JOIN in the SQL:

```
"DELETE FROM Database1." + @[User::TableName] 
 + " FROM Database1." + @[User::TableName] 
 + " JOIN Database2." + @[User::TableName]
 + " ON {SomeCondition} 
WHERE CreateDate < DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE())"
```

In the above pseudocode, I am assuming that the Schema of the table is included in the value of `@[User::TableName]`.   If it isn't, you will have to include it in the query.